# C# Get CheckSum XOR Error in hexadecimal conversion

Tags: c#

Sorry for the rudimentary question.
I am writing code to calculate a checksum as follows

```
public void GetCheckSum()
{
//test data1 
//The answer is 61
//var hexInput = "43-33-30-30-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-32-03";

//test data2
//The answer is 42
var hexInput = "54-33-30-30-20-20-20-20-38-2E-30-03";

var splitByte=hexInput.Split("-").Select(hex => Convert.ToByte(hex)); 
byte[] byteData = splitByte.ToArray();

byte checksumTest = new byte();

for(int i = 0; i < byteData.Length; i++)
{

    checkSumTest = (byte)(checkSumTest ^ byteData[i]);

}

Console.WriteLine(checkSumTest);
```

For test data1, I get the desired value of 61.
However, test data2 gives an error with the byte conversion of "2E".

ERROR : Input string was not in a correct format

How should I handle hexadecimal numbers like "2E"?

Comment: To be clear, they’re all hex, and it’s a slight coincidence that if you treat them all as decimal and write the answer as decimal it’s the same as treating them all as hex and writing the answer as hex for that input. If it were 34 instead of 33, you would get different answers (correct is 0x66, decimal gives 62).

Comment: It's not wrong but it seems pretty pointless having that `splitByte` variable. You're already chaining two method calls so why not just chain three: `var bytes = hexInput.Split('-').Select(hex => Convert.ToByte(hex, 16)).ToArray();`? You could even replace your loop with an `Aggregate` call if you fancied, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: You could also get rid of the `ToArray` call and use a `foreach` loop on the result of `Select`. That array isn't really required, unless you want it for some other purpose too.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
You are right, as you pointed out, the code you taught me is leaner and better.
Aggregate is new to me. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `Convert.ToByte(hex, 16)` to indicate that the input represents a number in base 16.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have confirmed that 2E is converted to 46.
However, when converted to 46, the value of the test data2 checksum is not the value I want....
The value I am looking for is 42, but it is a different value, 2A.
The checksum is calculated at the following site
https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/

Comment: @BTOM, if the calculation you're using doesn't produce the expected result then you're using the wrong calculation, but that's irrelevant to this question. The question you specifically asked was about converting hex values with letters in them. I have answered the question you asked. Accept the answer provided. If you now have a new question then post a new question and provide ALL and ONLY the information relevant to that question. You don't ask one question and then add more once that gets answered.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
We will examine the content and post it as a new question.